# Using bitwise to multiply by 5/8 function in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I've been trying to figure out the error in my code but I can't seem to figure out what the error is. I've walked throguh each line and it makes sense.

The goal is to multiply by 5/8ths rounding toward 0 and preventing overflow. Order of operations is multiplying by 5 then dividing by eight (i.e. 11 * 5/8 = 6). The goal for optimization is to use 12 or less operators.

The stipulations are that only ! ~ & ^ | + << >> operations

My current attempt at the solution is

```
    int mul = (x << 2) + x;   // multiplying by 5

    int bias = (mul >> 31) & 7;   // add 2^3 - 1 = 7 before right shift if number is negative

    int result = (mul + bias) >> 3;  // divide by 8 after adding the bias

    return result;
}
```

I'm getting this message

ERROR: Test trueFiveEighths(-2147483648[0x80000000]) failed... ...Gives -268435456[0xf0000000]. Should be -1342177280[0xb0000000]

Comment: You have a failing example, can you figure out in which step it does something bad?

Comment: Anyway, a solution seems to be divide first, multiply second, handle the remainder after division.

Comment: Hint:  what is `x<<2` for the value in the ERROR message.  Does it overflow?

Comment: Here's a hint. Use `long long` instead of `int` to reduce the possibility of overflow.

Comment: int64_t x2 = x + x; return (x2 + x2 + x + ((7UL) & (x2 >> 63))) >> 3.